# What ports are needed to be open in a Sitecore environment?

Tags: infrastructure

Anyone have an infrastructure diagram or documentation with the ports used in a multi-server Sitecore environment?  We want to start with everything locked down and only open ports being used.

Modules/Services being used are:
-WFFM
-EXM
-SQL Server
-GatherContent
-Coveo Cloud
-Sitecore AD Module
-Leveraging mLab for hosted MongoDB

Comment: For Coveo Cloud, you need your Sitecore server to be able to communicate outbound with the Coveo Cloud servers. The list of IPs: http://www.coveo.com/go?dest=cloudhelp&lcid=9&context=194

Answer (score 10):

I don't have an infrastructure diagram, but here is some highlights of the ports you will need to open to establish the communication between Sitecore and the modules/services.

1. **[WFFM](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/save_actions/specify_different_smtp_settings_for_the_send_email_message_save_action) & [EXM](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/setting_up_exm/configuration/the_exm_configuration_settings)**: The Sitecore will use a SMTP server to send emails, and will depends how the email server is set. **The standard port for SMTP is 587**. In this case your SMTP server needs to allow connections on **TCP/587**.
2. **SQL Server**: **The standard port for SQL Server is 1433** and you will need a rule at the SQL Server to allow connections on **TCP/1433**
3. **[Coveo Cloud](https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/cloud/coveo_cloud_v1_and_v2_platform_ip_addresses_to_whitelist.htm)**: Coveo Cloud is already set to accept connections on its ports and if you are blocking outbound connections, then you'll need to allow outbound connections to the follow IPs:

   . 54.84.109.253
   . 54.84.122.250
   . 54.84.126.201
   . 54.84.126.206

**BONUS - Local Coveo** If you are interested in know the ports used by the Coveo Platform, please [click here](https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/ports_used_by_the_coveo_platform.htm) for more details. Here are the ports: TCP/52800; TCP/52810; TCP/8081; TCP/8080; TCP/1980; TCP/56000; TCP/5682; TCP/52580; TCP/15672

4. **[AD Module](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Active_Directory/1_3/Active_Directory_1_3.aspx)**: **Active Directory listens on port 389** and for **Active Directory Profile Provider port 445**, so your AD needs to accept connections on these ports.
5. **[mLAB](http://docs.mlab.com/security/#custom-firewalls)**: First of all you'll need to find your [database connection info](http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#connect-string) by following the steps
   . Log in to the mLab management portal
   . Navigate to the MongoDB deployment that you wish to connect to
   . At the top of the screen, you will see a box with the connection information
   [image: mydb]
   In the picture above, notice that the server address is **ds012345.mlab.com** and the port used is **56789**, which means every mLAB setup is unique and hostname and port are different from deployment to deployment. Using the picture as an example, you will need to allow connections to **the port 56789**

**BONUS - mLAB** [Dedicated plans offer the ability for you to define custom firewall rules](http://docs.mlab.com/security/#custom-firewalls) so that your database only allows network access from your application infrastructure. By doing it, you will have the option to add the Sitecore box public IP, and you guarantee that ONLY that Sitecore box will be able to access your mLAB MongoDB deployment.

Comment: SQL Server Standard Port is 1433, will Sitecore work with Dynamic ports ?

Comment: @Sivalingaamorthy whenever your SQL is not using the default standards, you must provide such information in the ConnectionStrings.config by adding a comma and port number, please see the example below <add name="web" connectionString="user id=myuser;password=secretpassword;Data Source=sqlserver,1435;Database=mywebdatabase" /> which means I am telling to Sitecore that my sqlserver listens on 1434 port instead.